# compare all adjacent columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list('xyz'), (5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

print df

   A  B  C  D
0  x  z  x  z
1  y  z  x  z
2  y  z  x  x
3  y  y  y  x
4  y  x  z  z
```

I'd like to compare columns `A` with `B`, `B` with `C`, and `C` with `D`.
I know I can do `df.A == df.B`, but is there a way to easily compare all columns with their adjacent columns?

I'd like to see

```
       B      C      D
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False   True
3   True   True  False
4  False  False   True
```

I've tried this

```
pd.concat([df.iloc[:, i] == df.iloc[:, i+1] for i in range(df.shape[1]-1)], axis=1, keys=df.columns.tolist()[1:])
```

Which is how I got the desired output.  Efficiency is important, so I feel my attempt is inadequate.  If these were `float`s or `int`s, I could

```
df.diff(axis=1) == 0
```

But they're strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `shift(axis=1)`

```
(df == df.shift(axis=1)).iloc[:, 1:]
```

[image]